# How to delete product images for deleted products?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

We have two different situations.

- Out of stock products that have many images that we need to delete
  the extras without the base image
- Deleted products that still have images in the media folder

We need to remove those images in a small code that can do it fast enough without doing any damage.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate which images are currently assigned to any product in your catalog by reviewing **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery** database table. For instance...

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query = $readConnection->select()
    ->from($resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery'))
    ->group('value_id');

$imagesInUse = array();
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
foreach ($results as $item){
    $imagesInUse[] = $item['value'];
}
```

Now you have all images in use in 
**$imagesInUse** array, so you could iterate through **media/catalog/product** subfolders (ignoring cache and/or not relevant folders in your project) & delete any image not present in your array